# Grep and sort several unsorted things in several lines (in one document)

Tags: regex, list, sorting, grep

I have a file with several unsorted things in one line which I want to put into a new file

This is an example of part of the file I have:

```
X1314448: SaMi|SM_g2554.t1 SaMi|SM_g5072.t1 Des|Des_g3808.t1 Dul|Dul_comp50786_c0_seq1-1 Nig|Nig_comp88811_c0_seq2-1 AB|AB0003DMP400018076_AB0003DMT400026495 Phy|Phy_comp35647_c0_seq1-1 SWtf|SW_g27807.t1 Tom|Solyc02g077050.2.1
X1314810: Des|Des_g33587.t1 Nig|Nig_comp84357_c0_seq1-1 AB|AB0003DMP400020961_AB0003DMT400030857 Phy|Phy_comp33112_c0_seq1-1 SaMi|SM_g27352.t1 SWtf|SW_g21774.t1 TAIR|AT4G14930.1 Tom|Solyc06g054250.2.1 Dul|Dul_comp63657_c0_seq2-1
X1327159: AB|AB0003DMP400016823_AB0003DMT400024599 AB|AB0003DMP400017933_AB0003DMT400026257 Dul|Dul_comp58749_c0_seq2-1

X1330513: Des|Des_g36886.t1 AB|AB0003DMP400049952_AB0003DMT400073802 SWtf|SW_g16502.t1

X132738: Des|Des_g491.t1 Des|Des_g6171.t1 Dul|Dul_comp57659_c0_seq2-1 Dul|Dul_comp57659_c0_seq3-1 Dul|Dul_comp57659_c0_seq4-1 Ni                                                                       g|Nig_comp93106_c3_seq1-1 Nig|Nig_comp93106_c3_seq2-1 AB|AB0003DMP400005485_AB0003DMT400007895 AB|AB0003DMP400021388_PGS                                                                       C0003DMT400031553 Phy|Phy_comp61931_c0_seq1-1 Phy|Phy_comp61931_c0_seq2-1 Phy|Phy_comp61931_c0_seq3-1 Phy|Phy_comp61931_c0_seq4-1                                                                        RICE|LOC_Os08g43334.1 RICE|LOC_Os08g43334.2 RICE|LOC_Os09g35790.1 RICE|LOC_Os09g35790.2 SaMi|SM_g30888.t1 SaMi|SM_g5888.t1 SWtf|SW                                                                       _g17547.t1 SWtf|SW_g33717.t1 Des|Des_g47565.t1 SaMi|SM_g6027.t1 SWtf|SW_g42019.t1 TAIR|AT5G62020.1 Tom|Solyc03g026020.2.1 TAIR|AT4                                                                       G11660.1
```

What I want is to have the first part, "X1314448:" followed by by "Des|Des_g3808.t1”. And  if there is another “Des_xxx” (in some cases there are more than one, like in the second to last line), I want that to be included as well, followed by the “AB|AB00…” in the output file, but since it is an unsorted list I am uncertain how to sort out the three different parts I want while still keeping them on the same line (keeping them linked to each other). I am also not sure how to get several matches on one line like this.

So for the first line, the output should be:

```
X1314448: Des|Des_g3808.t1 AB|AB0003DMP400018076_AB0003DMT400026495
```

For the second to last last one:

```
X1330513: Des|Des_g36886.t1 AB|AB0003DMP400049952_AB0003DMT400073802
```

for the last one:

```
X132738: Des|Des_g491.t1 Des|Des_g6171.t1 Des|Des_g47565.t1 AB|AB0003DMP400005485_AB0003DMT400007895 AB|AB0003DMP400021388_PGSC0003DMT400031553
```

I think the main problem is the last line. I also want to be able to modify the file to 
have the "Dul|..." included as well.

I have tried several things, and it seems like the last line makes it impossible to use pipes and grep, although I am not sure, since I have seen some great things done using that method. I have some experience with Perl, but no idea how to solve this using it. I have also tried a bit using awk, which might be the best way to solve it, but I have no working solution using it either.

I am very grateful for any ideas on how to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Content of script.awk

```
# Ignore blank lines we put a condition NF which means only perform
# action on lines that are not blank

NF {

# Initialize variables

    x=y=""

# We print the fist column along with the FS variable which is blank by default

    printf "%s", $1

# We loop through the lines from second column until the very last

    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {

# If our column starts with Des then append our variable x with the value

        if ($i ~ /^Des/) {
            x = x FS $i
        }

# If our column starts with AB then append our variable y with the value

        else if ($i ~ /^AB/) {
            y = y FS $i
        }
    }

# Print variable y if x is empty else print both x and y

    print !x ? y : x y    

}
```

#### Test: Running against your inputdata

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
X1314448: Des|Des_g3808.t1 AB|AB0003DMP400018076_AB0003DMT400026495
X1314810: Des|Des_g33587.t1 AB|AB0003DMP400020961_AB0003DMT400030857
X1327159: AB|AB0003DMP400016823_AB0003DMT400024599 AB|AB0003DMP400017933_AB0003DMT400026257
X1330513: Des|Des_g36886.t1 AB|AB0003DMP400049952_AB0003DMT400073802
X132738: Des|Des_g491.t1 Des|Des_g6171.t1 Des|Des_g47565.t1 AB|AB0003DMP400005485_AB0003DMT400007895 AB|AB0003DMP400021388_PGS
```

Comment: I do not understand it, could you please add some explanation just so that I know enough to be able to apply this to some slightly different files later?

Comment: @user2478002 Updated with comments.

Comment: Thank you, that improved it a lot, although I still have the problem with the last line (that it is not sorted, I would want all "Des|D..." to follow X...). Any idea how to sort this?

Another thing that I want to do is make another file, where I have the "Dul|..." included as well, how would I edit this code to include it?

Comment: @Stenemo Updated the solution to keep `Des` entries first. For `Dul` you can reuse the existing script and change the `if loops`. If you run into any issues you can always post another question.

Comment: +1 for the superb effort

Comment: Thanks @1_CR :). OP posted this question on several SE sites desperately looking for a solution. I am hoping this would get him closer to his goal.